# Phonegap mobile server error

Tags: phonegap-plugins

I get this error on phonegap mobile server:

> unable to download archive from the server phonegap'.

How do I update the phone version?  Reinstall it?  I have tried to reinstall but still gives me the error.

Comment: post your error here...

Comment: it says loading..then download error.